# GCP VM Terminal gets stuck when I try to clone a git repo

Tags: linux, git, github, google-cloud-platform, ssh

I have been trying to make an application live for some time now using GCP , For some reason , I am not able to clone my repository over SSH, I have tried doing it with making the repo public and using https and then it works but this is annoying me a lot since its a private repo. SSH over public repo's also doesn't work.

It is getting stuck at this point

[image: 1]

I have tried changing the ssh keys , using another algorithm, changing my wifi network to another one

Comment: I have the same problem. Both for gitlab.com and github.com. `ssh -Tv git@github.com` just hangs forever.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to see you have a internet connection in your VM ?
how do you connect to VM via SSH/public IP or UI ?

I would say try to curl to github first and see if that goes through , it seems like your VM does not have internet access and you need to configure cloud router to fix it.

/Ehsan

Comment: The error message visible in the image of the terminal says that Git — actually SSH — connected to github.com and checked the host key. The connection seems to be ok.

Comment: It actually does not said connected it just says resolved , it's possible that dns server resolves the IP but the connection to that IP is not going through , it can happen in GCP environment if there is no router configured for accessing internet.

Comment: SSH fetched the remote host key. It surely connected and exchanged at least some bytes.